# Using the elimination method to solve an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to use the elimination method to find a general solution for the given linear system, where differentiation is with respect to $t$. It's been awhile since I've done this so if somebody could walk me through this that would be great!!

$x' = 4x-6y+sin(t)$

$y' = 3x-2y-cos(t)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the first equation and transform to
$$
y=\frac16(4x+\sin(t)-x')
$$
and insert it and its derivative into the second equation.